# single quote in namespace - schema parsing error

Tags: xml, cxf

We have created a CXF webservice client for external webservice which has the single quot in targetnamespace. Which is causing schema parsing error.
What can be done to resolve this?

If you need anymore information please let me know.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The XML namespaces recommendation states that an XML namespace name must be a URI according to RFC 3986. Apostrophes are reserved characters in the URI syntax, so a string containing an apostrophe may or may not be a valid URI depending on how it is used.

Unfortunately the XML namespaces recommendation allows but doesn't require parsers to check whether the namespace name is a valid RFC 3986 URI. This means that if it isn't valid, some tools will let you get away with it and others won't. Anyone who chooses an invalid URI as a namespace runs the risk that it will work with some tools and not others.

Comment: I really have no control over this target namespace as its the client currently running webservice on production and we are just suppose to use it. We need to findout a way how JBoss/CXF will help us to get this thing work.

Comment: Well, a good start would be to tell us what the namespace is, so we can see if it is actually a valid URI.

Comment: This is the target namespace, which causing parsing error
<schema targetNamespace='EurotaxGlass's/WebServices/LDES'....